# "Can't find a source file ...random.cc" with Eclipse CDT while debugging in c++

Tags: c++, debugging

[caption2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ln6Q.jpg)
i've been stucked with the generation of random numbers on one code i've been working lately. If i run the code, everything works fine. It only gets stucked while debugging... With this being said i share with you the code (of the .cpp file):

```
#include "RWS.h"
#include "Utilitaries.h"
#include <random>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

...

```
std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> U_01(0.0, 1.0);
```

We are trying to generate random numbers (differents than 0). This is the error from the debugger:

```
Can't find a source file at "/home/gfortran/gcc-home/workshop/gcc/objdir64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/../../../../../gcc-8.2.0-mingw/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/random.cc" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

I have a similar problem with another random generator, but i fixed it by Locating the file in the minGW folder. The problem now, is that i can't find the random.cc file, i can only see one file (in one minGW folder: C:\MinGW\include\c++\8.2.0\bits) which is named random.tcc and i believe it has something to do with that. But i'm not really familiar with this. Actually, i haven't seen any .cc file in these folders... Can you explain me why the debugger is not working and how i can overcome this please?

Comment: Can't you just "jump over" the implementation of the random numbers and trust that it works? Otherwise you can download a copy of the libstdc++ source code and point your debugger to that, but it will not teach you much.

Comment: I can't jump over it because it gets stucked in that error. I just don't understand why it worked while running but the debugger can't find the files

Comment: Because that file is a part of the libstdc++ library, to which you do not have the sources installed. Normally a debugger can just jump over it, unless you get stuck in some kind of crash or breakpoint? In that case you should post the stack trace at that point and any other information the debugger prints (like a segmentation fault or an exception)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have downloaded the libstdc++ library from this site https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3. Can you please tell me, where do i have to put the extracted documents?

Comment: There is no set path as far as I know. You need to configure your debugger's source path. Normally your IDE should ask to locate the file if it does not find it in its default paths.

Comment: Ok so, i downloaded the library, and i link it to the "Source" tab in the Edit configuration for the Debug... Then when i do the debug it freezes again at the same spot and asked what i already put over there (basically what you said), but when i locate it, it opens the random.cc file... Then i click on F6 (for a Step over), and it doesn't continue to the next line. And then it terminates the debugging...

Comment: As I said, you really do not need the source code of functions you step over. I suspect your program crashes somewhere inside the random number generator. What is the stack trace at the moment your debugger pauses? If you're not sure, attach a screenshot of the moment its get stuck.

Comment: Hi Botjie, I followed the code, it gets stucked exactly in the line
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
When i see the Expressions tab in the Debugger, i can see there are many errors:

Comment: Nothing else? No stack trace? No pending exception? No signal? If you're unsure how to interpret everything, just post a screenshot.

Comment: Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * gen(rd())
Error message from debugger back end: No symbol "rd" in current context.
Is this the Stack trace?

Comment: No, a stack trace would consist of a few lines of function calls, all one below the other. You may need to enable debug symbols when compiling as well.

Comment: i have added the image in my post Botje

Comment: Remove that expression and switch to the values tab. That will tell you the values of all local variables.

Comment: It seems i have others errors. I edited the caption

Comment: I'm running the code in Windows with that random generator. I had to changed it to the basic rand() genrator so i could run it in Linux... So now i'm sure the problem came with the "std::mt19937 gen(rd())" expression

Comment: At this point the thread is getting long ,but check the value of `token`. The code seems to be assuming it is a number, and it may not be. (or point to a wrong location, I don't know.)